# IE 7,8 automatically adding line breaks after every <a> tag

Tags: internet-explorer-8, hyperlink, internet-explorer-7, line-breaks

My site is bumping every single `<a>` tag to a new line throughout the site, but only in IE 7 and 8.

It looks fine in IE 9, Chrome, Safarai and Firefox. Even with `<a>` nested in various other elements.

I have tried adjusting `line-height`, which helps the lines from overlapping, but still bumps every `<a>` tag to the next line.

I have also tried `display:inline`, to which nothing changed at all.

I have searched for every single style applied to `<a>` in my stylesheet that does not play nice with IE 7/8. Still nothing.

Comment: Try display:inline !important;

Comment: Wow, that worked! So simple, yet beautiful! Thanks so much!!

Comment: Do I need to mark this as solved somewhere? Not seeing it...

Comment: @smclark89 should add an actual answer (not a comment) and then you should accept it